# Extracting a key pair values from a Json string using regex

Tags: json, regex

I have a Json that has been converted as string from which I would like to extract a key pair value.
For example, I have the following Json before it was converted to string

```
{
    "key1": "value1"
        ,
     "key2": "value2"
}
```

I would like to extract the key pair value

```
"key1": "value1"
```

The regex I made for matching the entry is the following:

```
("key1"((\s)*?):((\s)*?)"value1" and I replace it with empty.
```

My regex does not match the `,` and therefore, I still have the trailing comma after my operation.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does what I needed to do

```
"key1"((\s)*?):((\s)*?)"value1"((\s)*?),
```

I can then replace that with empty